# Sending Facebook notifications to multiple users from index.php

Tags: facebook, notifications, push-notification

We have an app with 100.000 users. We want to send weekly notifications to all of them at one instance.

We've read all the documantation and sent notifications to test users one by one. But unfortunately we wewren't able to send them all at one instance.

Any one can help and show us a way to do that?

Thanx